# Port unavailable in Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a three node Kubernetes cluster and a deployment with 5 replicas. Each pod of the deployment exposes port :3401 and :4000 (one for debugging, and one for the application). I have two services (one for each port the pods expose). I have an ingress controller, and a single ingress for the application that is exposed by the application service.

Three of my pods are able to start while the other two log the following error:

```
 main: error: server error: listen tcp :3401: bind: address already in use
```

Is it possible to have more pods than nodes listening on a single port using Kubernetes? If so, where would I go about debugging this issue?

Comment: Could you please add YAML manifests for the resources you've mentioned? Usually every pod has its own IP address, so I assume that you have something node network related there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the following lines in my pod spec for the deployment:

```
 hostNetwork: true
```

Must have copied and pasted it from somewhere without thinking. :(